# 97 Honda CRV overheating and radiator fan not turning on by itself

Tags: honda, overheating, crv, fan

I have a 97 Honda CRV that is overheating while standing still. The temp gauge will go up to 3/4 mark and the radiator fan will not turn on. I can turn the A/C on or heat at max and the temp starts dropping.

First I had to fix the temp gauge as that wasn't reading correctly. It is now reading correctly. Both fans turn on with the A/C. The radiator fan turns on when jumped at the connector. Upper and lower radiator hose gets hot. Coolant reservoir is filled to max.

I have replaced:
1. temp gauge sender (gauge wasn't reading right)
2. thermostat (thinking this was the gauge issue)
3. Radiator fan (it was seized)
4. Cooling fan fuse (under hood, I think the seized fan blew it)
5. Coolant/radiator fan switch (twice thinking I got a dud)

Is there anything else I should look into?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the fan relay under the hood?

Comment: Thanks @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 for the welcome! I have checked the fan relay and swapped it with another one in the car. It seems to be good as the radiator fan turn on when jumping the switch connector.

Comment: Have you tried using an OBD2 reader to see if you can see the engine temperature (more reliable than looking at the gauge)? Also, does it eat coolant?

Answer (score 3):

A laser sight infrared temp gun would tell you what you need to know.  16 dollars on amazon.

When you jump the fan switch and the fans come on, you have reduced the possibilities down to:

1. You still have a bad switch.  You could test the operation with an ohmmeter and getting creative with some boiling water and a meat thermometer.  If the switch is bad, use a different manufacturer, preferably oem.
2. The sensor is fine but the coolant isn't hot enough at that spot, which leads to a coolant flow problem.
3. The engine isn't actually getting as hot as your guage is reading.

A temp gun will help replace perceptions with real data.

Comment: If it's #3, on a 97-01 CR-V at least, that is likely a bad sending unit, correct?